Node.js start fails on Linux platform due to invalid ELF header error
I'm trying to create a nodejs app on windows that only runs on linux, when building I install the dependencies like this "SET "npm_config_arch=ia32" ; SET "npm_config_target_arch=ia32" ; SET "npm_config_platform=linux" ; Yarn install" (as suggested here https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2221#issuecomment-872021336)
but it goes wrong
/home/pi/test/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:57
throw err;
^

Error: /home/pi/test/node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node: invalid ELF header
at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1452:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
at bindings (/home/pi/test/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/test/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js:1:37)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32) {
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

Node.js v18.19.1

if I install everything directly on raspberry it obviously works, but I need node_modules to be created on my machine, which is not raspberry
